# IndexError: list index out of range in VSCode but works well in colabs

Tags: python-3.x, list, wordnet

I'm trying to learn entailments in wordnet by rewriting code from a book. The code works well when I code it in colabs, but when I move it in VSCode, I receive an error message:`IndexError: list index out of range`

The code is like this:

```
for action in ['walk', 'eat', 'digest']:
  action_syn=wn.synsets(action, pos='v')[0]
  print(action_syn, '-->', action_syn.entailments())
```

with problem indicates in here:
`action_syn=wn.synsets(action, pos='v')[0]`

Can you please explain to me why this happens and how to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`list index out of range` in `wn.synsets(action, pos='v')[0]` would mean that there is no element `[0]`. Which means `wn.synsets()` has returned an empty list.

If you want the code to be more sturdy, check the list length before using it:

```
synset = wn.sysets(action,pos='v')
if len(myList)==0:
  print("Not found")
else:
  action_syn = synset[0]
  #...your other code
```

Of course you should be finding entries for "walk" as a verb, so I'd guess wordnet was installed correctly on colab and has not been installed correctly on your local machine (or wherever you are running vscode). I'd start that troubleshooting here: https://www.nltk.org/install.html